# 2 Databases. If value does not exists in the first one then look/search in the second one

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two **databases** lets name them db1, db2 respectively. In both I have a table named 'users' with a userid and a password fields.

The problem is: if a user does no exist in the first database; then, look/search in the second one.

Kinda new with SQL Server so this is what I have so far...

```
if exists(select userid from db1 where userid='whatever')
    select * from db1 where userid='whatever'
else
    select * from db2 where userid='whatever'
```

My question is, is this the best way to perform this? Is there any other way to do it? If so, please share...

Comment: Select keyword looks for values in Tables. Do you have two tables or two databases?

Comment: I have two different databases. In both I have the same table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `@@ROWCOUNT` function which returns the number of rows affected or read by the last statement.

```
select * from db1.dbo.users where userid='whatever'
 IF(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
  BEGIN
   select * from db2.dbo.users where userid='whatever'
  END
```